# Include new items into Objects (PHP)

Tags: php, oop

As you see below, we have `price` and `name` properties for each Object row. I want to include one more property, `category`, into **each row**. So, tricky question here: how can I do it?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [price] => 12.99
            [name] => Million Dollar Baby (Two-Disc Widescreen)
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [price] => 599.95
            [name] => Screets Kiddiebank Experience
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [price] => 1999.00
            [name] => Screets Kiddiebank Unlimited
        )

)
```

Comment: One category property with the same value for all of them?

Comment: @netcoder: good question... no, it should be different..

Comment: what is an "Object row" ? is the object something like [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)?

Comment: @jcinacio: sorry for the strange name I gave. I meant each item of the Object has `price` and `name`... I need to include `category` with different values. that's all..

Comment: Saying "it would be harder thank you think" isn't contributing much to your question: it's vague and doesn't help anyone address the particular difficulty you're having.

Comment: @Weston C: yes, you right. I edited my question. Sorry for confusing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are loooking for?

```
<?php
$p1 = new stdClass();
$p1->price = 12.99;
$p1->name = "Million Dollar Baby (Two-Disc Widescreen)";

$p2 = new stdClass();
$p2->price = 599.95;
$p2->name = "Screets Kiddiebank Experience";

$p3 = new stdClass();
$p3->price = 1999.00;
$p3->name = "Screets Kiddiebank Unlimited";

$products = array($p1, $p2, $p3);
foreach($products as $product) {
    $product->category = "Some category";
}

var_dump($products);
?>
```

Comment: I can't believe it, it's so clever answer. thank you so much... it works very well :))

Comment: PLEASE NOTE THAT: `foreach` in the answer is the key of my question. It helps me to include new DATA into my Object without suffering.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$objects->{0}->category = 'foo';
$objects->{1}->category = 'bar';
$objects->{2}->category = 'foo';
```

Comment: `foreach` above is the answer of my question. thanks thought :)